# I can't figure out what I'm missing, code works 100% except for one option

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The code below adds totals of check boxes and gives a discount if ALL are checked. And I got it working great, but for some reason when I use the "CHECK ALL" button, and then manually uncheck one of the boxes, it sets the total to -119, rather than to 476. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-con" href="../favicon.ico" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 

<!-- Begin JavaScript -->
<!--- ADDING THE CHECK BOXES WITH SELECT ALL DISCOUNT --->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  //Define global form total:
  var form_amount=0;
  
  //Define function to check if all boxes are selected:
  function allChecked()
        {
         for (xx=0; xx < document.WisBundle.elements.length; xx++)
         {
             if (document.WisBundle.elements[xx].type == 'checkbox' && document.WisBundle.elements[xx].checked == false)
              return false;
              if (checked == false){
                form_amount = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < document.WisBundle.elements.length; i++)
                {
                    if (document.WisBundle.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                        form_amount += parseFloat(document.WisBundle.elements[i].value);
                    }
                }
                checked = true;
                document.WisBundle.amount.value = form_amount;
    
                }
         }
         return true;
        }
        

        
  //Define function to manipulate the form total per item selected/deselected:
  function CheckChoice(whichbox)
     {
     //If box was checked, accumulate the checkbox value as the form total,
     //Otherwise, reduce the form total by the checkbox value:
     if (whichbox.checked == false)
        { form_amount -= eval(whichbox.value); }
     else    { form_amount += eval(whichbox.value); }

     //Re-set displayed total on form:
     document.WisBundle.amount.value = eval(form_amount);
     
     //If all the boxes are checkec, display the total as 999.00 giving them a discount:
     if(allChecked())
      document.WisBundle.amount.value = '999.00';
        else
      //Re-set displayed total on form:
      document.WisBundle.amount.value = eval(form_amount);
     }
    

  //Define function to init the form on reload:
  function InitForm()
     {
     //Reset the displayed total on form:
     document.WisBundle.amount.value='0';
     //Set all checkboxes on form to unchecked:
     for (xx=0; xx < document.WisBundle.elements.length; xx++)
     {
         if (document.WisBundle.elements[xx].type == 'checkbox')
        {
        document.WisBundle.elements[xx].checked = false;
        }
     }
  }

    //Check and uncheck all checkboxes:
    checked=false;
    function checkedAll () {
        var aa= document.WisBundle;
         if (checked == false)
              {
               checked = true
               document.WisBundle.amount.value = '999.00';
              }
            else
              {
              checked = false
              document.WisBundle.amount.value = '0';
              form_amount = 0;
              }
                //white checked is true do this
                for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) 
                    {
                     aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
                    }
          }
</script>

 

<title>Add Boxes</title>
</head>

<body>

            
            <form action="BLANKPAGE_TEST_2.cfm" method="post" id="addCommentForm" name="WisBundle" onsubmit="return submit_form()">
            
            
            <input type="button" name="UnCheckAll" value="Check / Uncheck All" onclick='checkedAll();'>
            
            <!--- <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll();'> Select All</label> --->
            <hr />

                <table id="commentTable">
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Item One</label></th>
                    <td>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="ItemOne" value="119.00" onclick="CheckChoice(this);" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();" class="checkbox" /> $119</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Item Two</label></th>
                    <td>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="ItemTwo" value="119.00" onclick="CheckChoice(this);" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();" class="checkbox" /> $119</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Item Three</label></th>
                    <td>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="ItemThree" value="119.00" onclick="CheckChoice(this);" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();" class="checkbox" /> $119</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Item Four</label></th>
                    <td>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="ItemFour" value="119.00" onclick="CheckChoice(this);" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();" class="checkbox" /> $119</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Item Five</label></th>
                    <td>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="ItemFive" value="119.00" onclick="CheckChoice(this);" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();" class="checkbox" /> $119</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="altTH"><label>Total $:</label></th>
                    <td class="altTD"><input type="text" name="amount" readonly="readonly" class="inputSmall" /></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't update `form_amount` inside `checkedAll()` when `checked` is `false`.

**Updated:** After having read through all the comments I thought it would be easier to refactor your javascript, now it does what you expect it to do.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var discounted_amount = 999.00;
    var isAllChecked = false;

    function allChecked() {
        var elements = document.WisBundle.elements;
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && elements[i].checked == false)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    function calculateAmount() {
        var amount = 0.0;
        for (i = 0; i < document.WisBundle.elements.length; i++) {
            var element = document.WisBundle.elements[i];
            if (element.type == 'checkbox' && element.checked) {
                amount += parseFloat(document.WisBundle.elements[i].value);
            }
        }
        return (allChecked() ? discounted_amount : amount).toFixed(2);
    }

    function CheckChoice(whichbox) {
        document.WisBundle.amount.value = calculateAmount();
    }

    function checkedAll() {
        isAllChecked = !isAllChecked; // toggle checked state (true -> false, false -> true)
        var elements = document.WisBundle.elements;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            elements[i].checked = isAllChecked;
        document.WisBundle.amount.value = calculateAmount();
    }

    function InitForm() {
        var elements = document.WisBundle.elements;
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox')
                elements[i].checked = false;
        document.WisBundle.amount.value = calculateAmount();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I've updated my code above. Hm it doesn't seem to work. It's giving me a weird total now: 0119.00119.00119.00119.00119.00

Comment: @Amir: Sorry, I didn't notice that your prices are strings, use parseFloat() to convert them to float numbers. See the updated answer.

Comment: (Updated code) Hmm no that still didn't work. Now the first check box starts at 595 and if I use check all, then uncheck one.. I'm back to the -119 problem :(

Comment: @Amir: I refactored your javascript code, now it does what you want.

Comment: This is really fantastic! Thank you so much it works perfectly! I wish you had added more comments to the code you did, I'd love to learn a bit more because it looks like what I did was off by quite a bit, but you did it short and precise. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Amir: I really glad I helped you. Which parts are not clear to you?

Comment: Well I guess I was just wondering on step by step logic, on how you got to this. Because I'd been wresting with this problem for a good two days before posting here and you solved it in 2 sec.